# SQL Server 2008: SQL Query using IF in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, if-statement

I have a colum like this in my query with SQL Server 2008

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'
```

In this column, some data value is `01/01/1900`.

What i want is if this column's value `01/01/1900`, then get `null` instead of `01/01/1900`

How can i do that?

This is full select part in my sql

```
SELECT  B.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + A.TEKLIF_NO2 AS 'TEKLIF',
B.MUS_K_ISIM, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ISL_TAR,103) AS 'TARIH',
SUM(ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN', 
    (CASE WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS 'KUR',
    D.AVUKAT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.ICRA_TAR,103) AS 'İCRA TARİHİ', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'
```

Comment: @Konerak Yes you are right but i don't know how can i use with CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) with Case When Then?

Comment: @Konerak http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx I use it for formatting date and keep it varchar for some reason.

Comment: @Konerak Yes SQL Server. I forgat write which server. I edit post.

Comment: I added the tag. Now the experts can help :)

Comment: @Konerak Thanks. Still waiting (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about how conversion works on SQL Server but try this:

```
   (CASE
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.ISL_TAR, 103) = '01/01/1900' THEN
       NULL
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.ISL_TAR, 103)
    END) AS 'TARIH'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `NULLIF` statement:

```
nullif(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.HACIZ_TAR,103), '01/01/1900') AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'
```

Comment: it's also solution. Thank for advice.